# Grouping string into substring based on randomized length

Tags: java

Using math.random(), I have to generate a string made up of numbers from 0-9 (inclusive) based off a random length from 25-50 (inclusive). I do this in the method stringAdd(). Then with the generated string, I have to essentially "group" it based on the length so that eventually I can add it to a total. If the length is above 30, I would group it by 3, otherwise, just group by 2. I need to use substring for this.

The first thing I do is make a loop for the generated string:

```
String randomString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   int numbers = (int)(Math.random()*10);
   randomString = randomString + numbers;
}
System.out.println("Generated string: " + randomString);
```

length is the parameter of the method. I pass in randomLength (int randomLength = (int)(Math.random() * (50 - 25) + 1) + 25;) in main. Upon running it, the randomized length was 30.

```
Generated string: 445870958423418563903977492822
```

Then I make a loop for "grouping" the string, but this is where I'm stuck. The output I want would be something like...

```
Group: 44
Group: 58
Group: 70
Group: 95
```

...and so on...

But I'm not too sure how to go on about it. I try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length ;i++)
{
   if(length > 30)
      System.out.println("Group: " + randomString.substring(i, 3));
   else
      System.out.println("Group: " + randomString.substring(i, 2));
}
```

But then the output is this:

```
Group: 0175
Group: 175
Group: 75
Group: 5
Group:
```

until it goes into an out of bounds exception.

Is there a simple way of doing this without anything too advanced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `i += 2` or `i += 3` instead of `i++`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s="4458709584234185639039774928229";
    int length = s.length();
    int step = 2;
    if (length > 30) step = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += step)
        System.out.println("Group: " + s.substring(i, Math.min(length, i + step)));
}
```

output

```
Group: 445
Group: 870
Group: 958
Group: 423
Group: 418
Group: 563
Group: 903
Group: 977
Group: 492
Group: 822
Group: 9
```

Comment: Great way of doing it. Is there an alternative way of approaching this without using Math.min() ?

Comment: `Math.min(a, b)` -> `(a < b ? a : b)`